# Shell to run StreamSets Pipeline

Tags: shell, scripting, streamsets

I want to connect to the Control Hub and want to run the particular **StreamSets** **pipeline** using Shell Script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are two problems with this question (at least): 1. It isn't particularly clear what the control hub and StreamSets are (the tag has no information to help guide those of us who haven't encountered the technology — which isn't your fault).  2. It isn't clear what difficulty you're facing.  If you want to write a shell script, do so.  What commands are provided by StreamSets to support this?  You should probably show what you've tried.  Maybe you could/should provide links to the doucmentation you're using.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.

Comment: Also, you might do better to ask in the StreamSets community - there are multiple options, including a dedicated Q&A site: https://streamsets.com/community/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the StreamSets Control Hub web UI, click on **RESTful API** and then **Job Runner**. You will see instructions for authenticating from the command line using `curl`. Scroll down and you will see the API for starting a job given the job id.

Putting them together, you'll need to do something like:

```
# login to Control Hub security app
curl -X POST -d '{"userName":"SCHUserID", "password": "SCHUserPassword"}' \
https://cloud.streamsets.com/security/public-rest/v1/authentication/login \
--header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "X-Requested-By:SCH" \
-c cookie.txt

# generate auth token from security app
sessionToken=$(cat cookie.txt | grep SSO | rev | grep -o '^\S*' | rev)
echo "Generated session token : $sessionToken"

# Start a job using the auth token
curl -X GET https://cloud.streamsets.com/jobrunner/rest/v1/job/{jobId}/start \
--header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "X-Requested-By:SCH" \
--header "X-SS-REST-CALL:true" --header "X-SS-User-Auth-Token:$sessionToken" \
-i
```

Comment: This is an ample script for calling SDC REST API when Control Hub is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using streamsets locally the other answer is not valid for you. Check `http://localhost:18630/collector/restapi` for more details.